# Why UtcDateTime function is not adding the offset to the UTC date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

For instantaneous DateTime tracking, I am using a `DateTimeOffset` datatype. The following function adds the user corresponding TimeZone ID offset to the UTC DateTime property of `DateTimeOffset`

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset), `UtcDateTime` will perform both a time zone conversion and a type conversion on a `DateTimeOffset`. The following code does not though. Why is the conversion not taking place?

Function to add TimeSpan offset,

```
public static DateTimeOffset GetUtcDateTime (DateTime sourceDateTime, string timeZoneId) {
 TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById (timeZoneId);
 TimeSpan offset = timeZone.GetUtcOffset (sourceDateTime);
 DateTimeOffset utcTime = new DateTimeOffset (sourceDateTime, offset);
 return utcTime;
 }
```

and here where I am trying to convert,

```
DateTimeOffset utcDate = (DateTime.UtcNow);
DateTime fromUtc = utcDate.DateTime;
DateTimeOffset UtcDate = StaticHandlers.GetUtcDateTime (fromUtc, "America/Los_Angeles");
Console.WriteLine ("UTC now is {0} and UTC Date LA is {1} and UtcDateTime LA is {2}", utcDate, UtcDate, utcDate.UtcDateTime);
```

the output is,

> UTC now is 5/8/18 6:43:37 AM +00:00 and and UTC Date LA is 5/8/18
>   6:43:37 AM -07:00 UtcDateTime LA is 5/8/18 6:43:37 AM

## update,

I want to preserve both UTC and the user offset for tracking purposes. DST matters in this context. The example below shows what I am talking about.

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime beforeDST_LA = new DateTime (2018, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime afterDST_LA = new DateTime (2018, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan offsetCurrent = tzi.GetUtcOffset (currentDateTime);
TimeSpan offsetBeforeDST = tzi.GetUtcOffset (beforeDST_LA);
TimeSpan offsetAfterDST = tzi.GetUtcOffset (afterDST_LA);
Console.WriteLine (&quot;Current offset is {0} before DST is {1} and After DST is {2}&quot;, offsetCurrent, offsetBeforeDST, offsetAfterDST);
```

> Current offset is -07:00:00 before DST is -08:00:00 and After DST is
>   -07:00:00

Comment: The output looks correct.  5/8/18 6:43:37 AM UTC is 5/8/18 6:43:37 AM UTC everywhere, even in LA.   The local time zone will, of course, have an offset from UTC

Comment: so the `UtcDateTime  LA` part of the output should not go back 7 hours?

Comment: Correct.  UTC's historical base is London time (with no daylight savings time).  So it's exactly the same everywhere in the world.  It never has time zone problems because it totally ignores them.  That's why we like it in IT ;-).   It's only local times that have offsets.

Comment: so basically what I am doing here is wrong, shall I store DateTime.Now along with the offset?

Comment: How can I do the conversion here then? I mean showing the time 7 hours behind as in the above example?

Comment: Handling time zones initially appears simple, but it can rapidly become complicated.  Different people have different preferences.  I personally prefer to use UTC everywhere - the only place I use local is when the user enters data or else for presentation to the user.  Not knowing too much about your precise needs, I would suggest that you follow that pattern - UTC for all your tracking times, and then when you display to the user you convert, using the user's time zone.

Comment: I have two requirements, one is for logging and tracking and this involves different time zones , the second is appointments. The latter I don’t need an offset for it. I will use UTC and present it at local time.

Comment: This is why in the example above I aimed to preserve both, UTC and the offset but I don’t know if what I am doing is right or not ?

Comment: I personally would not preserve both even for the tracking - it's a form of data redundancy.  Besides, local time is different for an observer in LA and an observer in NY.   Or for the same observer if he changes time-zone..

Comment: I didn’t mean to have two sets of DateTimeOffSet, I meant in the same DateTimeOffSet storing UTC and user offset from TimeZoneID. Sorry about this extended comments I am really confused about the proper way to handle it. For tracking DST matters and without saving the real offset the DateTime will be wrong. I will update my question to show what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would not call your function `GetUtcDateTime`, because that's not what it does.  It is trying to get a `DateTimeOffset` for a specific time zone for a specific time, so call it something like `GetDateTimeOffset`.

The main concept you're missing in your code is that `DateTime` has `.Kind` property, which sets a `DateTimeKind` value.  The kind is taken into consideration by several places in your code:

- `GetUtcOffset` will convert `Utc` or `Local` kinds to the zone provided before determining the offset.
- `new DateTimeOffset` (the constructor) will error if the kind and the offset conflict, if you provide an offset.
- When you assign a `DateTime` to a `DateTimeOffset`, the implicit conversion is evaluating the kind.
- When you call `.DateTime` from the `DateTimeOffset`, the kind will *always* be `Unspecified` - regardless of the offset.

If you take all of this into account, you'll realize you need to check the kind yourself before calling `GetUtcOffset`.  If it's *not* `Unspecified` then you'll need to convert it to the specified time zone before getting the offset.

```
public static DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffset(DateTime sourceDateTime, string timeZoneId)
{
    TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);

    // here, is where you need to convert
    if (sourceDateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
        sourceDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(sourceDateTime, timeZone);

    TimeSpan offset = timeZone.GetUtcOffset(sourceDateTime);
    return new DateTimeOffset(sourceDateTime, offset);
}
```

Now that this is handled, turn to the next set of problems, which is where you call it.

```
DateTimeOffset utcDate = (DateTime.UtcNow);
DateTime fromUtc = utcDate.DateTime;
```

In line 1, the implicit cast from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` sets the offset to `00:00` - because `DateTime.UtcNow` has `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc`.

In line 2, the call to the `.DateTime` property sets `fromUtc.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  Essentially, you've stripped away the kind.

So instead of this, just pass `DateTime.UtcNow` directly into the function.  The kind will persist, and it will all work - now that the `Kind` is recognized and the conversion is happening inside the function.

All that said, if your original values are all `DateTimeOffset` (example, `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`) then you don't need that function at all.  Just call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` with the `DateTimeOffset` directly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the elaborative response. `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` is my best bet here