# Replace TimeZone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, icalendar, nodatime

We are trying to build basic event calendaring functionality that allows a user to create an event and specify a start time at a given month, day, year, hour, and minute as well as a time zone (`System.TimeZoneInfo.Id`). The CMS system generates the resulting `System.DateTime` based on the location of our server, let's say `TimeZoneInfo.Id` **Mountain Standard Time**. The CMS does not provide an option with their date picker component to specify the time zone. We do however have control over the SQL datetime precision, by default set to `7`.

The `DateTime` gets formatted as `yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ` as for purposes of populating start/end times in an .ics/ical. With this format it makes May 25, 2018 7:00PM (`20180508T192840Z`) always look like the server's Mountain Standard Time (MST) rather than May 25, 2018 7:00PM in selected Eastern Standard Time (EST).

How can I "replace" the time zone for the `DateTime` that is generated without changing the year/month/day/hour/minute with either `DateTime`, `DateTimeOffset`, `TimeZoneInfo`, `NodaTime`, or even `string` functions to format into `yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ`?

The following:

```
TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime1, destinationTimeZone);
```

or:

```
LocalDateTime fromLocal = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime1);
DateTimeZone fromZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Denver"];
ZonedDateTime fromZoned = fromLocal.InZoneLeniently(fromZone);

DateTimeZone toZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"];
ZonedDateTime toZoned = fromZoned.WithZone(toZone);
LocalDateTime toLocal = toZoned.LocalDateTime;
var result = toLocal.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
```

Creates a new `DateTime` with hour adjusted from CST to EST which wouldn't work as the goal is to have a `DateTime` with the original hour value but with `TimeZoneInfo.Id` **Eastern Standard Time**.

`DateTime` constructor doesn't seem to have a contructor that specifies `TimeZoneInfo`, only `DateTimeKind`.

How can this be done with some even such as a `DateTime` created from `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: For this application, the server time should really be set to GMT.

Comment: `DateTime` type is not time zone aware, everything it knows about zones is a `DateTimeKind`, which can be either `Local`, `Utc` or `Unspecified`. So I'm not quite sure what does it mean to replace time zone for `DateTime` without changing the ticks value. Could you please explain further?

You should use `DateTimeOffset` for dates with zone information included. It has a constructor with `TimeSpan` so you are able to provide time zone offset.

Comment: Do you want to convert the selected date time to the selected timezone and then just save the two?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The generated `DateTime` gets formatted in to "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ" for purposes of generating an .ics file for elements such as start time, end time, etc. This format is causing the start/end datetime to look like CST even with an .ics IANA time zone set. I've updated my question with this information. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

- You're format specifier includes a `Z` at the end.  This is treated by .Net's string formatting as a *character literal*, because it is not a valid [datetime formatting specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).  Note that formatting tokens are case sensitive.  As a literal, it is just copied to the output - just like the `T` is.  Thus, this string you generate is always going to be interpreted as UTC by anything that parses it, since that's what the `Z` means in the ISO 8601 standard.  That is ultimately the root cause of the problem you're facing.

  If you intended it to reflect an ambiguous local time (because time zone is elsewhere in your .ics perhaps?), then omit the `Z` entirely.  If you intended however to include the time zone offset, then you might use the `K` specifier for `DateTime` values, or perhaps the `zzz` specifier in conjunction with `DateTimeOffset` values - depending on your specific needs.
- As others pointed out, `DateTime` is not time zone aware, but also note that neither is `DateTimeOffset` in that it only tracks an offset from UTC and not a specific time zone.  For example, it can track `-07:00`, but it cannot tell you that it is in Mountain Time.  That is why Noda Time has its `ZonedDateTime` type.  .Net doesn't have any such built-in type on its own.
- In your code, not that that in the call to `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`, the `.Kind` of the `dateTime1` variable will be taken into account.  If it's `DateTimeKind.Utc`, then the result will be deterministic.  But if it's `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, or `DateTimeKind.Local`, then it will be treated as if it is in terms of the local computer's time zone - which is the *server* time zone in your case.
- Note that it is far better to write your code in a way that behaves the same *regardless* of what the server's time zone is set to.  This generally means avoiding `DateTimeKind.Local`, such as `DateTime.Now`, `TimeZoneInfo.Local`, and others.  Instead, use `DateTime.UtcNow` for getting the current `DateTime`.  Alternatively you can use either `DateTimeOffset.Now` or `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`, or one of the methods on Noda Time's `IClock` implementations.

At the end of the day, though there are several possible solutions to your problem, the simplest one to generate the current time as a string in a specific time zone would be:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcNow, destinationTimeZone);
string s = converted.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss");
```

OR you might want:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset utcNow = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
DateTimeOffset converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcNow, destinationTimeZone);
string s = converted.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmsszzz").Replace(":","");
```

Note the removal of the `:` via `Replace` at the end - that's because in the ISO 8601 *basic* format, the offset should be like `-0500` rather than `-05:00`.  Unfortunately there is no format specifier to get that directly.  (Only the ISO 8601 *extended* format uses the colon).

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` type is not time zone aware, everything it knows about zones is a `DateTimeKind`, which can be either `Local`, `Utc` or `Unspecified`. Zone information included into string representation will be based on `Kind` value and server time zone.

You should use `DateTimeOffset` for your scenario, which stores date time as well as time zone information in a single value:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now; /*your date time here*/
var destinationTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var zonedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), destinationTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset);
var dateTimeStr = zonedDateTime.ToString("o"/*your format goes here*/);
```

Comment: I feel this is definitely along the lines what we'd need to resolve our issue. Could you clarify how daylight savings can affect this code? Does  `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()` and `destinationTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset` automatically understand how to handle DST? Or does that need to be checked on  `destinationTimeZone` and add/substract something on the `DateTimeOffset`? Thanks!

Comment: `BaseUtcOffset` should not be used, as it explicitly does not handle DST, but rather `GetUtcOffset` which does. Also, blindly specifying `Unspecified` kind mishandles `Local` and `Utc` kinds, except when the local time zone happens to be Eastern. If you want a `DateTimeOffset`, ultimately, you'd want to write something like the `GetDateTimeOffset` method I gave in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50238442/634824).

Comment: However here it's not really necessary to use either, because one can just pass `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` to `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`, along with the destination time zone, and get the correct result without worrying about `DateTimeKind` or manually getting the offsets, etc.

Comment: @MattJohnson, thank you for your answer, a lot of useful info, but it seems to me that the issue OP has is slightly different. As far as I understood there are a datepicker and a timezone picker controls on the site, and date value selected by user should be converted to the ISO 8601 standard having specified timezone – the same ticks value, but different offset. And my answer is wrong if assumptions are.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky you should use `GetUtcOffset` instead of `BasUtcOffset` to get a time zone offset respecting DST, as Matt kindly mentioned.